# Bridging NDIS into local LAN

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, bridge

I'm out of my depth here.

I'm currently accessing the internet on my desktop PC via an NDIS USB connection to my cellphone which is accessing the internet via 3G.

I'd like a laptop to also share this internet connection. It's WiFI'd to a wireless router (Netgear WGR614). The desktop PC is connected RJ45'd to the wireless router.

So I've turned off DHCP on the wireless router, bridged the two networks via Windows 7's built in bridging and given the laptop a static address in the same subnet as the desktop PC.

Desktop PC reports: IP 192.168.0.83, Subnet 255.255.255.0, Gateway 192.168.0.1

Laptop reports: IP 169.254.56.171, Subnet 255.255.0.0, Gateway 192.168.0.1, despite me statically setting its IP to be 192.168.0.42, Subnet 255.255.255,0, Gateway and DNS 192.168.0.1.

Desktop PC is accessing internet, laptop of course isn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any success, @jontyc?

Answer (score -1):

No eggspurt but, DNS & gateway should have different addresses. I have similar setup, I give my ethernet card ny usb address in Preffered DNS for me 192.168.1.1 & gateway is the usb modem IP address. Works fine. USB is gateway & ethernet provides DNS

Comment: can you elaborate?